# Error while accessing .hdf5 file, shows error “OSError: Unable to open file ”

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems, hdf5, h5py

When I tried to open an .hdf5 file with h5py:

```py
import h5py

file=h5py.open(".../f.hdf5",'r'),
```

The following error was raised:

> h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()
>
> OSError: Unable to open file (unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable')

Answer (score 4):

Solutions: The error could be solved for opening .hdf5 files as below:

file= h5py.File(file_path,'r')

1. close the files using file.close()  or
2. import os
   os.environ["HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING"] = "FALSE"

Then the error while opening the file will be gone and you can keep working on that file.

Comment: Better yet, use the Python file context manager and you don't have to remember to close the file -- use `with h5py.File(file_path,'r') as file:`. This avoids problems when the program terminates unexpectedly and leaves the file open (because you didn't get to `file.close()` )

Comment: The `HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING` option solved my problem. Please add more details on this

Comment: I'd definitely advocate the with-statement solution provided by @kcw78. But in my case I used the mode 'r+' so my problem did not go away until I added the ```file.close()``` as the last line of the with-statement.